# MVC5 Entity Framework Partial Class Extended

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I've a problem about ASP.NET MVC5 and Entity Framework.
I work with an existing software database.
There is a table named "CLI" with lots of fields.

In my website, I've an Entity named "CLI". 
A "CLI" can be a client or a delivery address (it's the same table). The only difference is the value of one field (C_LIV_SEUL)

I've a partial class "CLI" with DataAnnontations likes "Required" etc. on multiple fields. 
The problem is that a Client and a Delivery Address doesn't have the same "Required".

Per example, for a Client, the field "C_NOM" is required.
For the Delivery Adress, "C_NOM" is not required.

In my view, when I've a form to update a Delivery Address, I don't display "C_NOM" because it isn't required. 
But when I've a view to update a Client, I display "C_NOM" because it's required.

How can I do this ?
I think about inheritance, but I can't apply changes on datacontext (because it isn't a "CLI" entity), or add an Entity with the type "Client" or "DeliveryAddress"...

I also try to work with the ModelState (ModelState.Remove("C_NOM")), but when I SaveChanges the error persists.

Thank you all for help!

Comment: "but I can't apply changes, or add an Entity" - how do you want to solve a problem if you can't change anything? You need to provide more details here. What do you expect from us? Why can't you "apply changes", why can't you add an entity? What exactly is your constraint?

Comment: Could you create two separate classes for a "Client" and a "DeliveryAddress"  and then add the same properties but with different attributes (Maybe have them inherit the same class for common properties). You will then have to convert them into your entity type when saving any changes.

Comment: @user2945722  AFAIK this can only be done with a discriminating column. Does the table have a discriminationg column ?

Comment: have you considered using only one entity but with a [custom validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx). This scenario is the closest from your database reality.

Comment: Yes, I've a discriminating column. 
Imagine I've a table CLI. With Entity Framework, I've an Entity "CLI" linked to the DataBase.
I can add, remove or update "CLI" Entity.
In reality, "CLI" can be a Client or a Delivery Address. It's the same table but one field is different. 
Required fields for a client isn't the same that the delivery address ones.
I've only one partial class "CLI" but how can I do to have different Required Field in my view ?